# Multipart in rest assured doesnot pass the files name properly

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

This is my code to rest my api to upload file

```
given().auth().preemptive().basic("*****","****").contentType("multipart/form-data").multiPart("type", "SAMPLE_XML").
multiPart("preview_file",new File("C://hello.xml")).
multiPart("connector_id", "MTUyMjMyNTU0NTMwNA").
when().post(Endpoint.FILE_CONTEXT_UPLOAD).
```

My API has a validation where it checks the file extension .xml when this request is made.For the above request my api doesnot receive .xml file extension and so it gives out 400 error

FYI the same request works fine using Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `contentType` to `("multipart/related;boundary=*****")`.